# Is there a way to confirm Events with Automatonymous?

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, masstransit, saga, automatonymous

I want to know if there is a way to confirm with Automatonymous, I want the following events to be executed if the previous ones have been completed.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking tbh.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to monitor a queue in the consumer with Automatonymous, so that when I publish the information to a queue, if the consumer completes the process, he tells Automatonymous that it is complete. And so Automatonymous continue with the following process. Thanks @AlexeyZimarev

Comment: What Automatinymous has to do with this? You can publish anything directly from your consumer.